# Paths of files are available to anyone even who are not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, paperclip

I'm building a kind of blog system with ruby on rails in my localhost.

I want only authenticated users to be able to see attached images.

Currently only authenticated users can read articles (by 'devise'), but even non-authenticated users can access to images via urls of them.

When I display a photo uploaded, the url of the image is shown and it's like this:
http://localhost:3000/system/assets/1/original/meadow.jpg?1306153343

So, what should I do to fix this?

---

**My Environment**

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 3.0.7

Rubygems 1.8.1

devise 1.3.4

paperclip 2.3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a method to download an image using **send_file**, so that you can check if a user is signed in.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html

http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right